# How to change the licence of Java project from GNU/ GPL to MIT / BSD / Apache

Tags: java, gnu, bsd, gpl

I had developed a Java application which is connected to MySQL Workbench by using `mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar` file.
When I deploy the project and send source code to the client he says that:

1. The license must not have a licensed GNU/ GPL / Unspecified that has a disclosure obligation (it is okay to have MIT / BSD / Apache without a disclosure obligation)
2. Change the GNU/GPL licence to MIT or BSD

Now my question is, how to change the licence of the project
or how to change the licence of library files like `Mysql connector.jar`.

Because I need a open source licence for the source code, So I need to change the licence libraries (used in project).